# taxonomy field error Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, office-integration

I am using an Office 365 custom solution

I have a  custom list with a couple of taxonomy fields. I have added some JavaScript to customize the fields i.e.hide and show the fields depending on some user rules.

At certain times I get this error `Access is denied.`

> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`.

When I update any fields(other than the term store fields ) and click on the save button to update the item.

The error seems to go away if I refresh the page and then update the list item.

The error did not arise because of permission to the specific term
    set .As even though I gave the user permission to the the specific
    terms sets. I still got the error. But if I refreshed the page and
    updated the item the error went away.

The term store is marked as closed. I tried making it open but did not make any difference.

**a)Under what conditions can I get a Access Denied error for the taxonomy term**

**b)Is there any place where you can enable/disable the Taxonomy validation access rules**

Answer (score 1):

When a Term Store(Taxonomy) is created it has its own permission level. Check whether the user context which your are using has permission to the Taxonomy or not.

See the picture I have attached.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I still get the error . I added the user as a contributor .  I also added the user to the Taxonomy hidden list with full rights.  I noticed one strange behaviour if I edit the taxonomy field value the error goes away.

Comment: Try Creating the terms again and provide the Contributors at the same time.